# Prenex Normal Form (Iff)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I translate iff to implication and then or/and form. But I can't distribute compound quantifiers on the equation in the picture link below. Can you help me to solve this to translate this equation to prenex normal form?

> $$\exists x \ \ \forall y\ \ \big(P(x,y)\leftrightarrow Q(y)\big)\rightarrow \forall\  x\ R(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

> But I can't distribute compound quantifiers on the equation in the picture link below.

In order to convert the given formula to prenex normal form

First you can get rid if the implication using,

> P → Q  ↔  ¬P ∨ Q

Then you will get,

> ¬ [∃x∀y (P(x,y) ↔ Q(y)) ] ∨  ∀ x R(x)

which in turn gives you

> ∀x∃y ¬(P(x,y) ↔ Q(y))  ∨  ∀x R(x)

Since the Universal quantifier doesn't distribute over ∨ you can do the following,

> ∀x∃y∀z[ ¬(P(x,y) ↔ Q(y))  ∨   R(z) ]

Now you can continue solving it as normal.

Hope this helps.